# Choices in automating Numbers

Tags: swift, applescript

My goal is to update a Numbers spreadsheet weekly.   I know how to schedule things with Launchd.  I know how to fetch files with data using wget.  I can use Awk or Python to extract the data I want from the files.  I find I can write applescript to update values in a Numbers by specifying the cell and value.

How do I put it all together?  Can I have python write a big string with 60-70 cell references and then call oascript?  I've found examples on the web on simple examples of python calling applescript.

Can I somehow use Swift as a scripting language to do it all?

All advice how to automate this task is appreciated.

Comment: It's easier to call a python script from AppleScript than vice versa. And Swift cannot use as a scripting language.

Comment: Without knowing any explicit information and data, I'd suggest you start by creating a flowchart of all the working pieces and writing the necessary code for each and then assemble it as appropriate. Obviously it needs to be written so that each segment is validated before moving onto the next. (In other words, use the appropriate error handling at each point as necessary.)

Comment: For non-trivial tasks calling AppleScript from Python [via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html) may be easiest.

Comment: Hm, the AppleScript-ObjC bridge for python looks interesting but it is not supported any more.   I could get the example to run as is but as soon as I tried to add a parameter to the handler function it fails with comments about the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: Sounds like your Python code is missing an underscore in the method name, e.g. `obj.foo()`, `obj.foo_(arg1)`, `obj.foo_bar_(arg1,arg2)`. See the [PyObjC documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/core/intro.html).

Comment: Hm, that fails with a message about "No Attribute test_"   I see what the documentation says but it doesn't seem to work when calling my Applescript function/handler.